# Installation mini.iso fails

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-minimal

We have tried to install mini.iso for ubuntu 16.04 which fails
to complete installation.

While installing libc6-udeb, it failed for unknown reasons.

It says
"An installation step failed. you can try to run the failing item 
The failing step is: Detect disks."

```
Failed to load installer component.
Loading libc6-udeb failed for unknown reasons. Aborting
```

Kindly advise how to install.
If you need more information, please ask.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the most up to date installer?
There is an incompatibility with the original installer and package updates (including `libc6-udeb`) that are downloaded in during the install process.

I have been having the same issue with a PXE installer that I use for unattended installs, after updating the netboot image & installer, the issue went away and I was able to successfully install 16.04

The most recent version, which worked for me, is available here - http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/

Thanks to Alex Brett at Citrix for the tip off on the Debain mailing list - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=833706#45

Answer (score 0):

It was reported as a bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+bug/1817358

In the comments, I found a build that shouldn't have that issue, but I didn't try it:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu451.27/images/netboot/mini.iso

I decided to switch to the 18.04 version, and I don't have that issue anymore.